# Dynamically changing the text of Label on Click in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My web html has following code

```
<script  src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script  src="js/jquery.rings.js"></script>
```

Contents of jquery.rings.js are :

```
$('input[type="image"]').click(function()
{
   $ring = $(this).data('my-info');
   $('label#ringName').text($ring['ringSetName']);
});


/***************************************************/
```

My Html code is fetching an array of rings

```
$db = new db();
$rings = $db->query("SELECT * FROM rings");
```

On runtime i am adding images in a slider as follow

```
<div class="albums-div">
    <ul class="slides">

        <?php



 foreach($rings as $ring)
          {
             echo '<li> <input type="image" src="' . $ring['ringThumbNailImagePath'] . '" name="checked" value="" data-my-info="' . $ring . '" width="150" height="150" /></li>';
           }   



         ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is , on Clicking the image nothing happens, the JS script seems not to be getting called.

tHE JS function should set the text of a label defined in the code as

What could be the problem?

Comment: _My Html code is fetching an array of rings_ - Oh look, a wizard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically added elements:

```
$(document).on('click','input[type="image"]',function()
{
  $ring = $(this).data('my-info');
  $('label#ringName').text($ring['ringSetName']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks , that's working however $ring = $(this).data('my-info'); this is not working, can you tell why i am not getting what i set as data?

Comment: $ring is not a text . Its a row from table.

Comment: but you are assigning `$(this).data('my-info');` value to it

Comment: How can I pass the entire row to jquery function then? Check the $rings and $ring in the code

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: do you mean parent `li` element of clicked img?? that would be `$(this).parent()`

Comment: no actually if i am doing this data-my-info="' . $ring['id'] . '" , the code works fine. However if i pass $ring only, and then i try to access anything $ring['id'] in the jquery function, it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, the second approach will not work. you can not use DOM object as attribute value.

Comment: any workaround? can u put some link how to use database to get the row from db from its id i will pass in jquery file

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically added elements:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

```
$('body').on('click','input[type="image"]',function()
{
   $ring = $(this).data('my-info');
   $('label#ringName').text($ring['ringSetName']);
});
```